# Why rawurldecode doesn't works?

Tags: php

I have UTF-8 string(from DB), and when i run:

```
echo rawurldecode('S = &#40; a &#43; b ) &#42; &#40; a &#43; b ) : 4');

as result i see:
'S = &#40; a &#43; b ) &#42; &#40; a &#43; b ) : 4'
```

I can't to get full access to this project. What can be wrong?

Comment: That string doesn't look like it was URL encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `&#40;`, for example, is HTML entity syntax, and not URL entity syntax. `%20%` is an example of how space (ascii 32 == 0x20) gets encoded.